# ¿Cómo ajustar la altura de un iframe al 100% para prevenir scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lo he estado intentado de varias maneras, con `js` y `css` pero no me funciona.

```
<iframe id="if" src="https:url..." frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" style="display:block; width:100%; height:100%;">
</iframe>
```

Ejemplo:

```html
<iframe id="if" src="https://es.stackoverflow.com/" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless="seamless" style="display:block; width:100%; height:100%;">
</iframe>
```

Si se fijan a pesar de poner el height a 100% no lo hace.

Por medio de un script que encontré en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9976309/4987172) tampoco tengo exito:

```js
  function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
```

```html
    <iframe id="if" src="https://es.stackoverflow.com/" onload="resizeIframe(this)" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless="seamless" style="display:block; width:100%; height:100%;">
    </iframe>
```

¿Hay alguna manera de lograrlo sin importar que ese iframe pertenezca a cualquier dominio?

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar un ejemplo que se pueda reproducir porfavor? Tu pregunta ahora mismo es susceptible de cerrarse como no reproducible.

Comment: en realidad no hace falta un ejemplo reproducible porque con cualquier link el problema aparece, es un problema conocido. Editaré mi pregunta pero no lo creo muy necesario

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta que comentas que encontraste tiene un comentario muy votado que dice que ese script no funcionará con contenido de otro dominio. Además, apunta a otra pregunta donde parece que han dado con [la solución](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42308842).

Comment: Exacto si desea que funcione el script propuesto debe estar el iframe bajo el mismo host que la aplicación contenedora

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es ocupar el 100% del ancho y del alto de la pantalla, prueba a usar las siguientes propiedades:

`width: 100vw;
height: 100vw`

Esto colocará tu elemento de forma que ocupe el 100% del ancho y del alto del viewport.

Así quedaría tu código:

```html
<iframe id="if" src="https://es.stackoverflow.com/" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless="seamless" style="display:block; width:100vw; height:100vh;">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

En un par de ocasiones que he necesitado hacer eso he usado el iFrameResizer de https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer y me ha funcionado bien.